Transactions getting stuck in tx pool, with ready status
I was testing sending multiple txs to a parachain node, with 1s of interval. And was receiving an invalid error in 10~20% of them.
Then I started to fix the invalid issue, and found a possible workaround to boot a new rpc node, and send the txs to that node.
That actually fixed the invalid problem, but another issue appeared.
Now, the transactions are getting queued in the tx pool and don't execute. They only execute when I restart the node and restart sending new txs.
I'm using polkadot v1.10.0, with rococo runtime for the relay and custom runtime for the parachains (Cumulus based).
It's a development network, so we had 4 validator nodes and 3 parachains running, each with 1 collator only.
Any kind of possible solutions or more info needed? Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks :)
EDIT
More info to add, there is a log that appears as well, but I don't know what might be causing it and if there is a relation to the issues I'm seeing.
Cluster has too many pending statements, something wrong with our connection to our group peers
[4198]: Restart might be needed if validator gets 0 backing rewards for more than 3-4 consecutive sessions pending_statements={ValidatorIndex(2): {(ValidatorIndex(2), CompactStatement::Seconded(0xd9268d1be792633f73a3284d6e596facfd8c134b53da8577135b53059a2b4bf0))}} parent_hash=0xe5da33a5db02c1f2b46587bec6193ae8c76fd64953f914bbc01390e7f185d782


TLDR: You are having the same issue as described here
What probably happens is that one of transactions you are sending is getting rejected, because of the bug linked above. Then you continue to send transactions, but they can not get applied because they use a higher nonce that actually first requires the rejected transactions to be applied.

I'm having the same problem here. Is there one version 1.09, 1.05 or lower where we don't have this issue? Or how to avoid these forks or prevent these transactions from being rejected?
